# Nasm add value to array

Tags: python, assembly, nasm

I have a nasm question!
I want to convert python code to nasm.
Here is python code:

```
y = [];
    for i in range(6):
        y.append(i);
```

Here is what i got:

```
    SECTION .bss
            Y: resb 30
            i: resb 30
   asm_main:
   ......
   mov edx,-1
   mov ecx,dword 6
   Y_loop:
      inc edx
      mov [Y + edx],edx
      cmp edx,ecx
      je Y_loop_end
      jmp Y_loop
   Y_loop_end:
   mov eax,Y
   call print_string
```

When i run the nasm, No output show out.

Please Help!
Thanks!

Comment: I think, The output should look like 012345

Comment: You're writing a bunch of unaligned dwords partially overlapping, which, while allowed (and not the cause of the problem), is odd and unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry about that! I think,it is copy and paste problem.

Comment: Sure. Anyway just change `dex` (I assume this means `edx`) into `dl`. Well you'll need more stuff there anyway, so turn it into `mov al, dl \ add al, 48 \ mov [Y + edx] al` (not tested)

Comment: Thank! It works now!

Answer (score 1):

Your string `Y`contains `0x000102030405`, which is not printable.

Comment: Thanks! How to fix that problem??

Comment: @HIABCD make your string `Y` contain something printable.

Answer (score 0):

What you do in memory, let's pretend some magic did set memory array at `Y` to 204 (to make progress of your code more obvious):

```
Y: CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC  ; (0xCC = 204)

      ...
   Y_loop:
      inc edx
      mov [Y + edx],edx
```

In first iteration the `inc` will modify `edx` to `0`, then the `mov` will modify the memory like this:

```
Y: 00 00 00 00 CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC  ; (0xCC = 204)
;  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^   modified
```

Four bytes are written, because `edx` is 32 bit (4B) register.

When `edx` is not 6, then the code loops, so again the same instructions, in second iteration will modify the memory to:

```
Y: 00 01 00 00 00 CC CC CC CC CC CC CC  ; (0xCC = 204)
;     ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^   modified
```

Then it will loop few more times, until `edx` will be 6, then it will exit loop, with final memory values set as this:

```
Y: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 00 00 00 CC CC  ; (0xCC = 204)
;        ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^  mod in next 4 loops
```

It looks like `mov [Y+edx],dl` would be probably enough for you, unless you want the three zeroes after `6`. That would store only single bytes.

Now this memory content is still not directly printable in terminal, as these values don't represent printable characters in any common char encoding.

But it is almost the same as the python version, except the `6` slipped in, while `range(6)` is only `0 .. 5`.

But you don't show how you output that python array of numbers. I'm pretty sure there's some implicit "int to string" conversion involved. That's not an option in Assembly, in Assembly your byte values are your byte values, and all the interpretation is left to you, no implicit shenanigans ever happen.

So to convert that memory content into `"012345"` ASCII encoded string, you have to add value `48` (`= 0x30 = '0'` !). That's what harold suggested in comment, but he modified the `Y:` memory content, so it went away from the `python` original, as suddenly you have "ASCII string" in memory, instead of array of byte [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] values. This may be nice, if you don't plan to further calculate with `Y[k]` values, because after conversion to ASCII `Y[0] + Y[1] = 48 + 49 = 97 = 'a'`, it's not `0 + 1 = 1` any more.

Other option is to loop through the `Y` array again, and produce string in other part of memory, keeping `Y` as byte values. Then you can also handle values which require more than single digit (as byte value `10` => 10 + 48 = 58 = `':'` printable character "colon"), by converting them into multi-digit string.

---

BTW, if I would want to produce string "012345" in `Y` in production-like code (not learning loops, arrays, etc.), I would code it as:

```
    lea   edi,[Y]  ; target buffer address
    ; try to write code into sub-routines, independent of global labels
    ; like the next two lines, which can be used to set any
    ; 6+ byte buffer to "0123456", just put address into edi
    mov   [edi],dword '0123'
    mov   [edi+4],word '45'
```